# SQL Query, Get data from multiple tables and query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table T1, which contains  which contains columns (A , B, C ,D) in which A is PK.

And I have some more tables. And I want to get some data from these tables.
I get the data as per my sql query from these tables.
Sql query (query1) is as follows

```
select t3.col1 as A, t3.col4 as F, t4.col as H
from t3, t4
where  t3.col1 = t4.col2;
```

Now
I want to get data from Table T1 and above query1 result.

```
select B , C , D , F,  H
from T1, Temp
where t1.A = Temp.A;
```

where Temp is the above sql query1 result.

How I can achieve this?

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using explicit join as in:

```
select t1.B, t1.C, ..., t3.col1 as A, t3.col4 as F, t4.col as H
from t3
join t4
    on t3.col1 = t4.col2
join t1
    on t1.A = t3.col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT t1.B as B, t1.C as B, t1.D as D, t3.col4 as F, t4.col as H
FROM t1, t3, t4
WHERE t1.A=t3.col1 AND t3.col1=t4.col2
```

Comment: query1 can be any other query, fetching data from multiple tables, here I have shown only 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join

**consider this exapmle**

lets say two table
1st one is "Order" 
and 
2nd is "Customer"

SELECT Orders.OrderID(table_name.column_name), Customers.CustomerName(table_name.column_name), Orders.OrderDate(table_name.column_name)
FROM Orders(1st table_name)
INNER JOIN Customers(2nd table_name)
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID(Must be matching field for joining);